# Rails: NOT NULL Violation: saving apparently circular associations sometimes lacks foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deep-copy

Using Ruby-on-Rails 5.2.3 with ruby 2.5

## Problem:

I've written in Rails a network-router configuration frontend, and this has some circular definitions, like this one:

- A Forward has many Addresses (that are forwarded).
- An Address has many Forwards (that do forward to it).
- An Address has many Forwards (for which the responses come in from it).

Addendum:
*As this may appear a bit weird at first glance, here is a little picture:
[image]One can see the three distinct associations between the two objects, where the "Address" in each association plays quite a different role. (But they can change roles or even play multilple ones - and thats exactly the point of the application: always generate a syntactically and logically correct configuration for the end device - and that part works already).*

Plus, obviousely is also needed:

- An Address belongs to an interface.

I built this in the usual way:

```
class Forward < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :nullify
  belongs_to :remoteip, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :responding, class_name: 'Address', optional: true
end
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :interface
  belongs_to :forward, optional: true
  has_many :remoteip_forwards, class_name: 'Forward',
           foreign_key: :remoteip_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :responding_forwards, class_name: 'Forward',
           foreign_key: :responding_id, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Then there are CONSTRAINTS on the Database, as objects must not be orphans, in thie case:

- address.interface_id NOT NULL

Then I have a top-level Design model, which chains together all the other models via proper associations, so I can grab one design and get all the stuff as one tree.

This all works just fine, so far. But when I try to copy an entire Design (with the `deep_clone` gem), when saving, **some** of the rather complex Designs give me `NotNullViolation`.

## Analysis:

Logs show that Rails does save some of the Address records *twice*: it does an `INSERT` with valid `forward_id` but **empty** `interface_id`, and only later does an `UPDATE` for the valid `interface_id`, all within the transaction.
And obviousely this kicks the `NOT NULL` constraint, and the action fails (when removing the constraint, the copy succeeds properly).

I would understand this if the actual design would indeed contain a circular reference (because then there is no other way to save it), but **there is none**! It is only *logically possible* to create circular references with these models.

I could not find proper documentation on how Rails handles such (potentially) circular things. `inverse_of` doesn't help anything (but that's to be expected, as my namings are well-defined).

When I use `autosafe: false` on the offending associations, the issue is resolved and Rails gets the tree saved - but then records which are not referenced twice, are missing in the copy (that's no surprize).

So it seems that the Rails code that walks the association tree to find and save the records is not fully extensive, and too early resorts on writing a record twice (probably to enhance performance?).

## How to approach this in the best way?

- Sadly, `NOT NULL` constraints are not `DEFERRABLE` in postgresql. Too bad, as that would seem the most charming solution.
- use `autosave=false`, walk the association tree by foot to find the proper sequence and save each record individually? No thanks.
- Layout the associations somehow differently? How? (I already have the working code that converts all the data for the targeted device, and that works well with the current layout.)
- Do away with the NOT NULL constraints? Hmm...
- Or, is there somewhere a knob in Rails that could be adjusted?

## Update

I have, for the time being, workarounded the issue as explained here: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/request-failures-lots-of-activerecord-not-nullviolation/79156
(The literal number 3 there might be made configurable, as it is a tradeoff between getting the associations resolved and running out of stack space.)

Comment: I think you really can solve this is a better and much more straight forward way by just creating one or two join tables `forwards` -> `responses(forward_id, address_id)` <- `address`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: The top three criteria should really tell you that you are looking two seperate many-to-many assocations and not one-to-one assocations. If you define the foreign keys on your addresses table that means that you can't link the same record to multiple other records.

Comment: Hey, thanks. In this case I'm sure these are not many-to-many, but three distinct one-to-many between the same two tables (I painted a little pic to clarify). Making them many-to-may seems rather going away from the real-world. But the core problem seems the potential circularity induced, and that won't go away with join tables (in sum I have 11 such constructs in the app, mostly involving the Address table). I'm currently looking at ActiveRecurd::AutosaveAssociation::ClassMethods.define_non_cyclic_method - it seems that potentially circular tree searches get intentionally blocked from there.